# Open a .xib file from code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xib

I want to display the contents of a .xib file when a button is pressed in my app. It would be the equivalent of the following in android:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity.this,classiwanttogoto.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there something equivalent to that in Cocoa Touch? I know that it is very easy with storyboards, and if it comes to that I will use it, but I would like iOS 4 support.

Comment: *but I would like iOS 4 support...* You might want to review some [iOS usage statistics](http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/) and rethink that.

Comment: decided to use storyboards instead. [This](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/9781449321123/4dot-storyboards/id3078924#X2ludGVybmFsX0h0bWxWaWV3P3htbGlkPTk3ODE0NDkzMjExMjMlMkZpZDMwNzg5MjQmcXVlcnk9) is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialize `UIViewControllers` like so:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNibName" bundle:nil];
```

And then you use it.

Or you can initialize a view from a nib:

```
UIView *myView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewName" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Which files do those go in?

Comment: Sorry? Didn't understood.